# query behind a report like e.g. getSkypeForBusinessDeviceUsageDistributionUserCounts

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

is there a way to query the Microsoft Graph API to get same information like those in a report, e.g. getSkypeForBusinessDeviceUsageDistributionUserCounts?

Report: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/reportroot_getskypeforbusinessdeviceusagedistributionusercounts

Reason: Reports return csv files. I would like to directly the data as JSON .

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Graph currently only supports return Reports as a CSV file. It is possible to retrieve it in another format (i.e. JSON or XML).

There is a similar request for JSON responses in the [Office Developers UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/19409305-allow-json-response-from-office-365-usage-graph-ap).

Comment: Thx for your answer!
I just found out that this feature is already available in the beta version. One can add "$format=application/json" to the end of the link, e.g:
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/reports/getTeamsDeviceUsageUserDetail(period='D7')?$format=application/json

See: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/reportroot_getteamsdeviceusageuserdetail

Comment: That is correct, however, keep in mind these are not suitable for a production environment. Beta endpoints can (and do) experience breaking changes without warning.